# Two numbers missing

Tags: riddle, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

In the following diagram can you fill in the two missing numbers (represented by the question marks)? Please explain your answer.

Please pay attention to the tags.

[image]

Hint 1

> The 2 numbers are Prime Numbers.

Hint 2

> See the new tag

Comment: I *think* the [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] tag fits here with the understanding that the answer aligns with the other presented tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two missing numbers are:

> 79 (central) and 53 (bottom).

Because:

> The green rectangles represent a simplified map of the countries and borders of central Europe! Specifically, the central country is **Austria**, one of the few countries of the world that has exactly 8 borders.
>
>  The positions of the other rectangles roughly correspond to the positions of the surrounding nations geographically, although a helpful confirmation of how to orient the image is to notice that the one labelled '3' is situated wholly between the central country and the one bottom-left marked '16' - this corresponds to Liechtenstein, which is landlocked between Austria and Switzerland.
>
>  Beginning top-left and proceeding clockwise, the full list of countries depicted here is:
>
>  Germany - 32
>  Czechia - 6
>  Slovakia - 16
>  Hungary - 1
>  Slovenia - 16
>  Italy - ?
>  Switzerland - 16
>  Liechtenstein - 3

What then do the numbers represent? Here, we need to use a second piece of knowledge...

> Noticing that all 3 of the countries marked with 16 just happen to begin with a letter 'S', ask yourself what other relationship there is between this letter and number and you should arrive at **atomic numbers of elements in the Periodic Table**, where sulfur (S) has atomic number 16.
>
>  In fact, there is a perfect correspondence for all the other countries too - the name of each begins with the symbol of a Periodic Table element which corresponds to its number:
>
>  **Ge**rmany - 32 (Germanium)
>  **C**zechia - 6 (Carbon)
>  **S**lovakia - 16 (Sulfur)
>  **H**ungary - 1 (Hydrogen)
>  **S**lovenia - 16 (Sulfur)
>  **I**taly - **53 (Iodine)**
>  **S**witzerland - 16 (Sulfur)
>  **Li**echtenstein - 3 (Lithium)
>
>  So **I**taly corresponds to **Iodine** with atomic number **53**, and **Au**stria corresponds to **Gold** with atomic number **79**.